# how to get the difference between two dates with timing

Tags: php, datetime

I have two dates that are in format `Y-m-d`

```
$dateOld = new DateTime("2017-01-10");
$dateNew = new DateTime("2017-01-11");

echo $diff = $dateNew->diff($dateOld)->format("%a");
```

this is working perfect and giving me exact days left.

But now I have added `time` and it is in `H-M` format

Like `23:38` and `17:21` and cannot understand now to get the difference between two `dateTime`

```
$dateOld = new DateTime("2017-01-10 23:38");
$dateNew = new DateTime("2017-01-11 17:21");

echo $diff = $dateNew->diff($dateOld)->format("%a");
```

I want to get the difference even if the value if in floating point. Now to work with date concatenated with time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
<?php
$dateOld = new DateTime("2017-01-10 23:38");
$dateNew = new DateTime("2017-01-11 17:21");

$diff = $dateNew->diff($dateOld);
$days = $diff->d;
$hours = $diff->h;
$minutes = $diff->i;

$total_difference = $days + ($hours * 60 + $minutes) / 1440;

echo $total_difference;
```

Or, without the DateInterval:

```
$dateOld = new DateTime("2017-01-10 23:38");
$dateNew = new DateTime("2017-01-12 17:21");

$difference_in_seconds = $dateNew->getTimestamp() - $dateOld->getTimestamp();

$total_difference_in_days = $difference_in_seconds / 86400;

echo $total_difference_in_days;
```

Using ->format("%a") will give you the **rounded** days.

See http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php.

Answer (score 0):

```
$dateNew = '2017-01-11 17:21'; 
$dateOld = '2017-01-10 23:38'; 


$dateNew = new DateTime($dateNew); 
$dateOld   = new DateTime($dateOld); 

$diff  = $dateNew->diff($dateOld); 

echo $diff->format("%H:%I");
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php